# Is there any way to parse to C program files using perl

Tags: c, perl, parsing

I want to parse C program files (.c extension) using perl. I want the parsing to be done in such a fashion like a sample c program may contain statement like

```
printf ("%d => Hello",x);
```

let x be a integer variable in the program. So when i parse the above line, is there any way of getting x value. Remember, i want to parse only one line and get the value of x, i cant parse any previous lines to obtain the value of x. Is there any way to obtain the actual value of x dynamically or is it better to parse object files.

Answer (score 11):

There is no tool in the world that may reliably find the value of x using the line `printf ("%d => Hello",x);`  only. The value depends on previous lines, and maybe on user input, which is not in the source code at all.

**Edit**

On the other hand, there are **a lot** of tools that work with C code, such as static analyzers, debuggers, interpreters and so on. You might want to look for one of those options.

Comment: And of course finding the value of `x` with a parser is complicated by that thing called the Halting Problem...

Comment: There are limits, yet there are levels of complication that those tools can handle.

Comment: Agreed.  Of course there are *some* programs (indeed, most real-world programs) that we can prove to terminate eventually, but a completely general solution to the problem is impossible.  That's not to mention that a parser is completely the wrong tool to solve these kinds of problems - a parser's job stops once the parse tree is built.

Answer (score 7):

No. Think about it:

```
int x = rand();
printf("%d", x);
```

How could you possibly know what `x` is without running the program?